# Why is Gibrien Marsden asking me to change citizenship?

Tags: everquest-2

I am playing as a gnome conjurer in EverQuest II. This is my second character on this account, so I got the option of starting in Kelethin. I am trying to fast-track citizenship in Kelethin so that I can get a house and store stuff there.

I have completed [Learning Faerlie](http://eq2.wikia.com/wiki/Learning_Faerlie) so that I can talk to the necessary NPCs, and I have a reputation of 40 000 with Kelethin. According to both [Considering Kelethin](http://eq2.wikia.com/wiki/Considering_Kelethin) and [Kelethin: Citizenship](http://eq2.wikia.com/wiki/Kelethin:_Citizenship) I need to speak to Gibrien Marsden to start the respective quest (before going to the Fae Royal Hall to speak to one of two NPCs there - I cannot access them at the moment).

However, when I speak to Gibrien, he asks me about *changing* citizenship. And offers me the choice of changing to Qeynos or Freeport. He does not offer me dialog options to get on the Kelethin citizenship track.

Is it possible that I am already a citizen? If so, how do I confirm this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that gnomes start as citizens of Kelethin, which includes being able to buy houses. (Found out by trying to buy one anyway.)